# why is 'monkey' a common password?

Tags: passwords

I was looking at [Wikipedias;List of the most common passwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_passwords) and saw 'monkey' listed 6 out of the last 7 years.

Most of the re-occurring passwords are fairly obvious choices.  But why is 'monkey' on the list (from 'SplashData') so many times?

Comment: People like monkeys?

Comment: It's going to be hard to get anything other than opinion on this question.

Comment: @baldPrussian Agreed. That's why I decided to put a flag on this post for it being opinion-based.

Comment: Cause the human brain is trash at thinking of random things, but it's not trash at making people think they've thought of a random thing. I'd bet if you went around to people and said "Say a random word in the next 5 seconds!" a large percentage of them would blurt out "Monkey!"

Comment: @JamesJenkins You will have a better chance getting a response for this in the Chat section. A good start would be probably be here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz

Comment: Maybe I should have posted this to https://psychology.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I suspect so.  Security SE is more about security practices and controls - if someone asks "why" it's generally to gain a technical understanding and a documentable, repeatable answer.  As a bunch of IT Security geeks, the "why" to this question probably involves saying something uncomplimentary about our users.  God Bless 'em, we love 'em, but sometimes they do silly things.

Answer (score 14):

Q: What kind of a key opens a banana? A: A monkey!